# How to include an input function for an I/O file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please have a look at the requirement below. Typically an input function is utilized as follows: it has a variable followed by an equal sign and then the input function with parenthesis of the wording.

```
name = input("what is your name?")
```

But in an I/O file, I wish to include this to an open/write/close process and in particular the write part of the process.

Obviously, this next line of code isn't it:

```
outfile = open("L7_2.csv","w")
outfile.write()
name = outfile.write(input("What is your First Name?"))
outfile.close()
print("L7_2.csv created")
```

Requirements

1. Write a program that will prompt the user for their
   first and last names
2. Using the "with" method, open X7_2.txt for writing
   and then write the first name and last name to a line in the file
   in the following format: Hi (firstname)
   and the last name to the next line in the file
   in the following format: Your lastname is (lastname)

Here is an example run...

```
What is your First Name? Steve
What is your Last Name? Perry
```

X7_2.txt created

```
Hi Steve
Your lastname is Perry
```

Comment: Look up [context managers](https://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html#context-managers). You might also want to review your lecture notes, textbook, or whatever other resources your course uses, because this should be clear from the question: _Using the "with" method..._

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
first_name = input("What is your name?") #Get first name
last_name = input("What is your last name?") #Get last name
with open("L7_2.txt",'w') as file: #Open the file in writing mode ensure the path is correct 
    file.write("Hi " + first_name + "\n" + "Your last name is " + last_name) #Write to the file with the strings separated by the new line
    file.close() #Always make sure to close your file!
```